# grails log4j active logger

Tags: grails, groovy, log4j, grails-2.0

Is it possible to activate | deactivate logger through `Config.groovy?`

for ex:

```
log4j = {

    appenders {

        file name:'connections', file: '/tmp/connection.log'
        file name:'view', file:'/tmp/view.log'
    }

    root {
        off 'connections', 'view'
    }


    info connections: "grails.app.controllers.ViewController",
            consultations: "grails.app.controllers.ConnectController"

}
```

How I can deactivate all 'connections' logger?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to de-activate all logging to a particular appender you can do that by setting the appender's *threshold*

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        file name:'connections', file: '/tmp/connection.log',
             threshold:org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF
```

but this will still create the `connection.log` file even though nothing is to be logged to it.  An alternative would be to take advantage of the fact that the log4j DSL is Groovy code:

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        if(config.log.connections) {
            // use a file appender for 'connections'
            file name:'connections', file: '/tmp/connection.log'
        } else {
            // use a NullAppender, which simply ignores anything it is
            // asked to log
            'null' name:'connections'
        }
```

This would let you switch 'connection' logging on or off using

```
log.connections=true
```

in the main part of `Config.groovy` (outside the log4j closure) or in an external file you have referenced using `grails.config.locations`.

Answer (score 0):

To deactivate, try this:

```
root {
    info 'connections', 'view'
}

off connections: 'grails.app.controllers.ViewController'
```

To activate, then change `off` back to `info`:

```
info connections: 'grails.app.controllers.ViewController'
```